# Detect if a section is available before @RenderSection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I have a piece of code which I would like to render conditionally, if a section exists...

```
<aside>
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
    @RenderSection("navigation", false)
</aside>
```

But I only want it to render if the section exists on the page; something like this

```
<aside>
    @if(SectionAvailable("navigation")) {
        <h1>Navigation</h1>
        @RenderSection("navigation", false)
    }
</aside>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `@if(IsSectionDefined("navigation")) { ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect if a section is defined like so:

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("navigation"))
{    
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
    @RenderSection("navigation", false)
}
```

[Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)